# Is having multiple SQLAlchemy sessions in the same controller okay, or should I put them all into one session?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

So I have a controller that renders a page. In the controller, I call multiple functions from the model that create its own sessions. For example:

```
def page(request):
    userid = authenticated_userid(request)
    user = User.get_by_id(userid)
    things = User.get_things()

    return {'user': user, 'things': things}
```

Where in the model I have:

```
class User:
    ...

    def get_by_id(self, userid):
        return DBSession.query(User)...

    def get_things(self):
        return DBSession.query(Thing)...
```

My question is, is creating a new session for each function optimal, or should I start a session in the controller and use the same session throughout the controller (assuming I'm both querying as well as inserting into the database in the controller)? Ex.

```
def page(request):
    session = DBSession()
    userid = authenticated_userid(request)
    user = User.get_by_id(userid, session)
    things = User.get_things(session)
    ...
    return {'user': user, 'things': things}

class User:
    ...

    def get_by_id(self, userid, session=None):
        if not session:
            session = DBSession()
        return session.query(User)...

    def get_things(self, session=None):
        if not session:
            session = DBSession()
        return session.query(Thing)...
```

Comment: get_by_id and get_things should be class methods if you wish to invoke those methods on the User object itself. From the looks of things you probably want "@classmethod get_by_id(cls, userid, session=None)", but get_things is just a method which can get the session from "session = object_session(self)". This is because after "user" is created, the session is accessible via the SQLA api on the "user" object itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first code is OK, if your `DBSession` is a `ScopedSession`. `DBSession()` is not a constructor then, but just an accessor function to thread-local storage. You might speed up things a bit by passing the session explicitly, but premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Or at least the root of all ugliness :D